# 1st Project: Sudoku Puzzle Assistance

Tags: python, arrays, matrix

I have this code to produce a prettier sudoku board. I was wondering why the last column of zeroes do not disappear as well. Other zeroes in columns disappear but not the last column. Also looking forward to some feedback.

```
board = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
         [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
         [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
         [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
         [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]

def print_board(board):
  print("-------------------------")
  for i in range(len(board)):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
      print("-------------------------")
    for t in range(len(board[0])):
      if t % 3 == 0:
        print("| ", end="")
      if t == 8:
        print(str(board[i][t]) + " |")
      else:
        if board[i][t] == 0:
          print(" " + "", end=" ")
        if board[i][t] != 0:
          print(str(board[i][t]) + "", end=" ")
  print("-------------------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a little helper function:

```py
def pr_el(val):
    if val == 0:
        return " "
    else:
        return str(val)
```

You can print the top row more easily just by allowing every `i%3==0` to print a line. Also, you don't need to handle the last character differently; just add another print for the final border on the line.
Then your code is:

```py
def print_board(board):
  for i in range(len(board)):
    if i % 3 == 0:
      print("-------------------------")
    for t in range(len(board[0])):
      if t % 3 == 0:
        print("| ", end="")
      print ( pr_el(board[i][t]), end=" ")
    print("|")

  print("-------------------------")
```

---

A [similar challenge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67441895/how-to-print-sudoku-grid-more-efficiently/67442186#67442186) woke me up to the possibility of printing the whole board at once, here using an inline `if` to switch zeroes to blanks (instead of the helper function) in a list comprehension to deliver the flattened board to a single `print`. The key change though is to use a multiline string with the `format` method to handle all values from the board array at once:

```py
def print_board(board):
    bar = "-------------------------\n"
    line = "| {} {} {} | {} {} {} | {} {} {} |\n"
    bd_fmt = bar + line*3 + bar + line*3 + bar + line*3 + bar
    print (bd_fmt.format(*((" " if el==0 else el) for rw in board for el in rw)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
board = [[5, 3, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0],
         [6, 0, 0, 1, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0],
         [0, 9, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0],
         [8, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 3],
         [4, 0, 0, 8, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1],
         [7, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 6],
         [0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 8, 0],
         [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 9, 0, 0, 5],
         [0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 7, 9]]

def print_board(board):
  print("-------------------------")
  for i in range(len(board)):
    if i % 3 == 0 and i != 0:
      print("-------------------------")
    for t in range(len(board[0])):
      if t % 3 == 0:
        print("| ", end="")
      if board[i][t] != 0:
          if t == 8:
            print(str(board[i][t]) + " |")
          else:
              print(str(board[i][t]) + "", end=" ")
      if board[i][t] == 0:
          if t == 8:
            print(" "+ " |")
          else:
            print(" " + "", end=" ")

  print("-------------------------")

print_board(board)
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
| 5 3   |   7   |       |
| 6     | 1 9 5 |       |
|   9 8 |       |   6   |
-------------------------
| 8     |   6   |     3 |
| 4     | 8   3 |     1 |
| 7     |   2   |     6 |
-------------------------
|   6   |       | 2 8   |
|       | 4 1 9 |     5 |
|       |   8   |   7 9 |
-------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

In an if/else block like the last one starting with `if t == 8:`, the `else` code only runs if the `if` statement above it is false.  So your code is only set up to handle whether or not the value is 0 when it's NOT looking at the last column.

You should only use if/else for mutually exclusive cases like `t % 3 == 0` and `t == 8`.