# How to print Sudoku grid more efficiently

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm Programming Sudoku game in terminal, I want to Print the grid to console with a square around it as in the picture below.
There is no problem with my code except it is inefficient.

I would like to get it more efficient and short (with list comprehensions, string multiplying, etc).
the board is defined like that,
board = [[_ for _ in range(9)] for _ in range(9)]

That is the function i'm using:

```
def Print_Board(board):

    print("\n-------------------------")

    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            if board[i][j] is not None:
                if j == 0:
                    print("|", end=" ")
                print(f"{board[i][j]} ", end="")
            if (j + 1) % 3 == 0:
                print("|", end=" ")
        if (i + 1) % 3 == 0:
            print("\n-------------------------", end=" ")
        print()
```

[image]

Comment: Unless you are printing this thousands of times, optimization isn't going to significantly improve performance.

Comment: Do not use `_` as a variable name if you are actually using its value.

Comment: I think sys.stdout is faster than normal print, altough the difference won't be noticeable unless you print extremely huge amount of sudoku which I guess you won't. I agree whith Niteya.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, minimize the number of `print()`s. Ideally, build a complete string representation of your game field and print it at once. Also, since your real numbers are going to be different, the question, as asked, is useless. You must first consider what data structure holds the game field, and then ask how to print it.

Answer (score 3):

You can build a board format and throw all the data at it:

```py
bar = '-------------------------\n'
lnf = '|' +(' {:}'*3 + ' |')*3 + '\n'
bft = bar + (lnf*3+bar)*3
print(bft.format(*(el for rw in board for el in rw)))
```

You only need to build the format once, of course. After that it's just a print.

---

---

Suggestion from JonSG in comments to encapsulate this in a closure:

```py
def make_board_printer():
    bar = '-------------------------\n'
    lnf = '|' +(' {:}'*3 + ' |')*3 + '\n'
    bft = bar + (lnf*3+bar)*3
    return (lambda bd:print(bft.format(*(el for rw in bd for el in rw))))
```

is a function which returns a board printer function:

```py
# make a printer:
b_print = make_board_printer()

# then as needed
b_print(board)
```

Comment: If I was really golfing, the bar would be a multiplication too :-).

Comment: You should add an extended answer that uses a closure to construct the template and return a lambda to print with it.

Comment: God I love this answer so much. Not just that it is short and sweet, but that it is conceptually great as well. Creating a print template that you can reuse takes the IO out of the format function and just as importantly, results in a single call to print(). Well done.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
def print_board(board):
    print("\n-------------------------")
    for row_num, row in enumerate(board):
        print("|", end=" ")
        for col_num, item in enumerate(row):
            print(item, end=" ")
            if (col_num + 1) % 3 == 0:
                print("|", end=" ")
        if (row_num + 1) % 3 == 0:
            print("\n-------------------------", end=" ")
        print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_board(board=[range(9) for _ in range(9)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a (not more readable) solution for your problem:

```
board = [range(1,10) for i in range(9)]
print("-"*25)
for idx, row in enumerate(board):
    rowStr = " | ".join([" ".join(map(str, row[i:i+3])) for i in range(0, len(row), 3)])
    print(f'| {rowStr} |')
    if (idx+1) % 3 == 0:
        print("-"*25)
```

Output:

```
-------------------------
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
-------------------------
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
-------------------------
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
| 1 2 3 | 4 5 6 | 7 8 9 |
-------------------------
```